# JQuery insert table row at postion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ive been working on a solution to being able to insert a row to a html table. Its been quite tricky. Ive found something that works but only for the first "insert". I cant figure out what im doing wrong.

Ive a basic table with 3 colums each table has a button to allow the insertion of a row between 2 rows. Ive searhed on this site for a solution and got a jquery solution that works i.e when i press the button it adds the row where i want it. But when i add another row after where i inserted the last row, the row is inserted 1 position back, the next time i press the button its inserted 2 rows back etc. I cant figure out what im doing wrong any one know why its doing this?

Even better is there a better way to do this? i.e add a row into a table at any postion?

JQuery code;

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".addRow").click(function(event){

    //get the button id to get the row
    var $id=this.id;
    var $totrecords;
    var $newrow;
    var $totalrowsadded;
    //get id of clicked button
    $id=$id.replace("add_", "");

    $totrecords=document.getElementById('totalrecords').value;
    $totrecords++;

    //store number of rows added
    $totalrowsadded=document.getElementById('totalrowsadded').value;
    $totalrowsadded++;
    document.getElementById('totalrowsadded').value=$totalrowsadded;

    //update record count
    document.getElementById('totalrecords').value=$totrecords;

    var $html='<tr class="newrow"><td>'+$totrecords+'<button type="button" class="addRow" id="add_'+$totrecords+'">add</button></td><td><label for="ProductHeight'+$totrecords+'">height</label><input name="data[Product][height'+$totrecords+']" type="text" value="0" id="ProductHeight'+$totrecords+'"/></td><td><label for="ProductWidth'+$totrecords+'">width</label><input name="data[Product][width'+$totrecords+']" type="text" value="0" id="ProductWidth'+$totrecords+'"/></td><td><label for="ProductPrice'+$totrecords+'">List Price</label><input name="data[Product][price'+$totrecords+']" type="text" id="ProductPrice'+$totrecords+'"/></td></tr>';


    $newrow=parseInt($id)+1;
    alert('new row insert at '+$newrow);

    $('#productstable > tbody> tr:nth-child(' + $newrow + ')').after($html);    


});
});

</script>
```

My table looks like this;

```
<table id="productstable">
    <tr>
        <th>Insert</th>
        <th>Height</th>
        <th>Width</th>
        <th>List price</th>
    </tr>

    <tbody>
    <tr id="0">
        <td>0 :<button type="button" class="addRow" id="add_0">add</button></td>
        <td><label for="ProductHeight0">height</label><input name="data[Product][height0]" type="text" value="115" id="ProductHeight0"/></td>
        <td><label for="ProductWidth0">width</label><input name="data[Product][width0]" type="text" value="595" id="ProductWidth0"/></td>
        <td><label for="ProductPrice0">List Price</label><input name="data[Product][price0]" type="text" id="ProductPrice0"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="1">
        <td>1 :<button type="button" class="addRow" id="add_1">add</button></td>
        <td><label for="ProductHeight1">height</label><input name="data[Product][height1]" type="text" value="140" id="ProductHeight1"/></td>
        <td><label for="ProductWidth1">width</label><input name="data[Product][width1]" type="text" value="295" id="ProductWidth1"/></td>
        <td><label for="ProductPrice1">List Price</label><input name="data[Product][price1]" type="text" id="ProductPrice1"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="2">
        <td>2 :<button type="button" class="addRow" id="add_2">add</button></td>
        <td><label for="ProductHeight2">height</label><input name="data[Product][height2]" type="text" value="140" id="ProductHeight2"/></td>
        <td><label for="ProductWidth2">width</label><input name="data[Product][width2]" type="text" value="395" id="ProductWidth2"/></td>
        <td><label for="ProductPrice2">List Price</label><input name="data[Product][price2]" type="text" id="ProductPrice2"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="3">
        <td>3 :<button type="button" class="addRow" id="add_3">add</button></td>
        <td><label for="ProductHeight3">height</label><input name="data[Product][height3]" type="text" value="140" id="ProductHeight3"/></td>
        <td><label for="ProductWidth3">width</label><input name="data[Product][width3]" type="text" value="495" id="ProductWidth3"/></td>
        <td><label for="ProductPrice3">List Price</label><input name="data[Product][price3]" type="text" id="ProductPrice3"/></td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the JQuery `append` function:

```
$('#productstable TBODY').append($html);
```

To add a row after the row containing the button that was clicked, use this:

```
$(this).closest('TR').after($html);
```

The `closest` function walks up the tree to find the nearest TR, then `after` will put it after it.

Comment: It's more like some kind of sorted list. You maxy want to take a look at the HTML code.

Comment: im using cakephp 2.0 so thats why the output is like that.

Comment: No, it should go to the end (inserts as the last child), see the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: i need to add a row at a certain position in the table i.e where the button is clicked.

Comment: Use the closest function, see above.

Comment: fantastic one line of code at it works, thanks so much and thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how you can append **after** a row: (you need to use `after` and not `append`)

```
$(".button_class").closest("tr").after("<tr>... contents of row ...</tr>");
```

Heres a [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/hesher/3Qhja/7/) that I wrote to demonstrate this.