# insert a tr in a table with jquery and selectors

Tags: jquery

my table is the second table in my page and im traying to copy the second tr of that table (becouse the first tr is in the thead and the other the tbody) and insert the copy into the same table how the first tr. Thx

```
firsttbodytr = $('form table:not(:first) tr:eq(2)').clone();

$('#crearb').click(function(){

    $('form table:last tbody').append(firsttbodytr);

});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery insert table row at postion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705198/jquery-insert-table-row-at-postion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [.prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/). Minimal example with your own code:

```
firsttbodytr = $('table:last tbody tr:first').clone();

$('button').click(function(){

    $('table:last tbody').prepend(firsttbodytr);

});
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/b5qk7evv/2/

Comment: Click on `CLONE` button to insert `tr` element.

Comment: i did bad my question, i was meaning more tr but just one at the time, thx by the way :)